Why setting the state inside a fetch callback (doesn't) cause an infinite loop?
I have the following code snippet, and I expected it to result in an infinite loop due to a state update inside a fetch callback inside the body of the component without using 'useEffect'. However, it's not behaving as expected. Here's the code:
function App() {
  const [cartContent, setCartContent] = useState(null);

  fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/carts/6")
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setCartContent("test");
    });

  console.log(cartContent);

  return <div className="cartContent">{cartContent}</div>;
}

export default App;

My understanding was that console.log(cartContent) should log the initial value of cartContent, then when setCartContent("test") is called inside the fetch callback, it should log "test", and this process should repeat indefinitely, creating an infinite loop.
Could someone please help me understand why this code doesn't result in an infinite loop as expected? Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

It does not cause an infinite loop since the value test is a string. The second call to setCartContent would set the same test value as the first call and it would look like the state did not change. Consider setting an object or any other value that changes equality/reference (e.g. previous !== current) to trigger the infinite loop.

Your expectation is a bit misguided. The code you have shared always updates the cartContent state to the string literal "test", but strings are kind of like primitives in that they are always equal to themselves, even when the variables holding those strings are different references. After the second enqueued state update is processed React see's the same state value and doesn't trigger any additional rerender.
See Bailing out of a State update:

If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
(React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)
Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree.


Because the fetch is directly inside the function component body and not inside a React lifecycle method like useEffect, it will only execute once. When this component is loaded and the execution reaches the fetch, it doesn't wait for the fetch to complete but executes the rest of the code, and the initial render is done. When setContent('test') eventually gets called and a re-render is triggered and only the return code is run.

because this should be inside an useEffect, or any other effect pacakge like react query

"I've verified that your code is functioning properly. You might consider incorporating it within a useEffect hook for improved organization, but overall, the code looks solid. Please review the other components."
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function App() {
const [cartContent, setCartContent] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/carts/6")

  .then((resp) => resp.json())

  .then((data) => {
    setCartContent("test");
  });

}, []);
}
